# Is it possible to check the history/log of the way merge conflicts where resolved with Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have multiple merges a day in between environments and we have the impression that some developers are using 'resolve using mine' when they should actually correct the merge.

Is there any way to have a report, log, history to indicate when merges where done the wrong way when using Subversion?

Comment: I may be wrong but I suspect this is entirely a client-side business that stays client-side. As far as I know the only trace that there was even a merge is the `svn:mergeinfo` property in the affected directory and it didn't even exist until version 1.5.